I have a password field that is "not interactable"
I have my site here:
AUT
with
<input type="password" class="gigya-input-password with-addon form-control" gigya-conditional:show-password-strength="screenset.width < 900?up" name="password" autocomplete="off" gigya-expression:data-display-name="screenset.translations['PASSWORD_73132891594356050_DISPLAY_NAME']" gigya-expression:data-gigya-placeholder="screenset.translations['PASSWORD_73132891594356050_PLACEHOLDER']" data-screenset-element-id="gigya-password-155327446633034050" data-screenset-element-id-publish="true" data-screenset-roles="instance" gigya-default-show-password-strength="null" gigya-default-data-display-name="null" gigya-default-data-gigya-placeholder="null" data-gigya-name="password" data-original-value="" id="gigya-password-155327446633034050" aria-required="true" show-password-strength="up" data-display-name="Gib dein Passwort ein." data-gigya-placeholder="Hier Passwort eingeben" placeholder="Hier Passwort eingeben" maxlength="100" data-attr-value="Login - Password" data-attr-element="formfield">

when I do the following:
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.className("gigya-input-password"));
password.sendKeys(PASSWORD);

or
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.className("gigya-input-password"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+PASSWORD+"')";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, myElement);

I get the following error:

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

How do I enter text into the field w/ selenium webdriver correct?
I already have a Thread.sleep(2000); to make element visible.
And
WebElement password = new WebDriverWait(driver, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("gigya-input-password")));

gives a TimeoutException.

its not really clear which field in a given link is the password field. post the HTML code of the form. you can add a screenshot of the form for more clarity as well.

added HTML to the  question

There are several instances of fields with class name gigya-input-password, you can check this by inspecting page and searching gigya-input-password. Selenium has no way of knowing which one you are after. I assume you want the one with the placeholder "Hier Passwort eingeben" if you search by "Hier Passwort eingeben" you can see that the one you want has the id "gigya-password-155327446633034050". This means you should be able to find it by id. Default CSS selector provided by chrome is #gigya-password-155327446633034050

By.className("gigya-input-password")

Above locator strategy is incorrect, it does not locate the targeted element. It returns 16 elements with that ClassName, see below.

Use the below XPath locator strategy instead:
By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Hier Passwort eingeben']")

